Arrow does not appear when the node is cdots in tikz-cd
I used the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.3ex]
&&&&\im f_i=\ker f_{i-1}\ar[dr,hook]&&\\
{\cdots}\ar[r]&M_{i+1}\ar[rr]{f_{i+1}}\ar[dr,twoheadrightarrow]&&M_i\ar[rr]{f_i}\ar[ur,twoheadrightarrow]&&M_{i-1}\ar[r,rightarrow]&{\cdots}\\
&&\im f_{i+1}=\ker f_i\ar[ur,hook]&&&&\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}

and it gave me this output:

For some reason, the arrows next to the \cdots do not appear. How do I fix this?

The arrow is only as long as the column sep of 0.3ex. That's not much. Choose a bigger one for whole matrix (maybe even with between origins) or just use &[<additional column sep>] in place of the first & and the last & in the first row.

You're using a very narrow column separation. But you can increase it at selected places by using &[<dimen>] in the first row.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0.3ex]
&[4ex] &&& \im f_i=\ker f_{i-1} \ar[dr,hook] &&[4ex] \\
{\cdots} \ar[r]
  & M_{i+1}\ar[rr]{f_{i+1}} \ar[dr,twoheadrightarrow]
  && M_i\ar[rr]{f_i} \ar[ur,twoheadrightarrow]
  && M_{i-1}\ar[r,rightarrow]
  & {\cdots} \\
&& \im f_{i+1}=\ker f_i \ar[ur,hook] &&&& \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


Alternatively, you can pretend that the objects in the top and bottom rows are shorter than they actually are.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& &&& \mathmakebox[1em]{\im f_i=\ker f_{i-1}} \ar[dr,hook] && \\
{\cdots} \ar[r]
  & M_{i+1}\ar[rr]{f_{i+1}} \ar[dr,twoheadrightarrow]
  && M_i\ar[rr]{f_i} \ar[ur,twoheadrightarrow]
  && M_{i-1}\ar[r,rightarrow]
  & {\cdots} \\
&& \mathmakebox[1em]{\im f_{i+1}=\ker f_i} \ar[ur,hook] &&&& \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}


